# Can anyone suggest package related to zooming images in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

i used zoomable_image plugin while doing zoom out images are not visible. so can any one suggest me any other plugin related to zooming in flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been working on something like that:
https://github.com/renancaraujo/photo_view

Give it a look and if you find any bug or suggestion, please, open an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this
[zoomable_image 1.2.0](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/zoomable_image)

Comment: But with this plugin, image zooms out too far and image scrolls out of the view.

Comment: yeah that's a problem. did you find anything useful ?